# How can I capture the cycle steps in time series data? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to isolate cycle steps and time, and then get the time delta between each cycle step. The dataframe has steps (rows) within each cycle that I am trying to ignore. This is a smaller version of what I was trying to do. My thought was to find the initial cycle start then get the next cycle step and so on and so forth, but my result tends to just append the first step only or just up to the first three. I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this.
[image: DataframeExample]

```
time = []
phase = []

a=1

for z in range(len(Cycle)):
    if Cycle['CycleStep'][z] == 1:
        tstart = Cycle.loc[z, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
        time.append(tstart)
        phasestart = Cycle.loc[z, 'CycleStep']
        phase.append(phasestart)
        b=z+a
        
        while Cycle['CycleStep'][b] != 2 and b<4325:
            b+=1

        if Cycle['CycleStep'][b] == 2:
            phase2 = Cycle.loc[b, 'CycleStep']
            time2 = Cycle.loc[b, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
            phase.append(phase2)
            time.append(time2)
            c=b+a
            
            while Cycle['CycleStep'][c] != 3 and c<4325:
                c+=1
            
            if Cycle['CycleStep'][c] == 3:
                phase3 = Cycle.loc[c, 'CycleStep']
                time3 = Cycle.loc[c, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
                phase.append(phase3)
                time.append(time3)
                d=c+a
                
                while (Cycle['CycleStep'][d] != 4 and d<4325:
                    d+=1
                    
                if Cycle['CycleStep'][d] == 4:
                    phase4 = Cycle.loc[d, 'CycleStep']
                    time4 = Cycle.loc[d, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
                    phase.append(phase4)
                    time.append(time4)
```

Comment: Can you show the expected result?

Comment: Basically cycle 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5 and the associates time stamps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = []
phase = []

a=1

for z in range(len(Cycle)):
    if Cycle['CycleStep'][z] == 1:
        tstart = Cycle.loc[z, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
        time.append(tstart)
        phasestart = Cycle.loc[z, 'CycleStep']
        phase.append(phasestart)
        b=z+a
        
        while Cycle['CycleStep'][b] != 2 and b<4325:
            b+=1

        if Cycle['CycleStep'][b] == 2:
            phase2 = Cycle.loc[b, 'CycleStep']
            time2 = Cycle.loc[b, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
            phase.append(phase2)
            time.append(time2)
            c=b+a
            
            while Cycle['CycleStep'][c] != 3:
                c+=1
            
            if Cycle['CycleStep'][c] == 3:
                phase3 = Cycle.loc[c, 'CycleStep']
                time3 = Cycle.loc[c, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
                phase.append(phase3)
                time.append(time3)
                d=c+a
                
                while Cycle['CycleStep'][d] != 4:
                    d+=1
                    
                if Cycle['CycleStep'][d] == 4:
                    phase4 = Cycle.loc[d, 'CycleStep']
                    time4 = Cycle.loc[d, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
                    phase.append(phase4)
                    time.append(time4)
                    e=d+a
                    
                    while Cycle['CycleStep'][e] != 5:
                        e+=1
                    
                    if Cycle['CycleStep'][e] == 5:
                        phase5 = Cycle.loc[e, 'CycleStep']
                        time5 = Cycle.loc[e, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
                        phase.append(phase5)
                        time.append(time5)
                        f=e+a
                        
                        while Cycle['CycleStep'][f] != 6:
                            f+=1
                        
                        if Cycle['CycleStep'][f] == 6:
                            phase6 = Cycle.loc[f, 'CycleStep']
                            time6 = Cycle.loc[f, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
                            phase.append(phase6)
                            time.append(time6)
                            g=f+a
                            
                            while Cycle['CycleStep'][g] != 7:
                                g+=1
                            
                            if Cycle['CycleStep'][g] == 7:
                                phase7 = Cycle.loc[g, 'CycleStep']
                                time7 = Cycle.loc[g, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
                                phase.append(phase7)
                                time.append(time7)
                                h=g+a
                                
                                while Cycle['CycleStep'][h] != 8:
                                    h+=1
                                
                                
                                if Cycle['CycleStep'][h] == 8:
                                    phase8 = Cycle.loc[h, 'CycleStep']
                                    time8 = Cycle.loc[h, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
                                    phase.append(phase8)
                                    time.append(time8)
                                    i=h+a
                                    
                                    while Cycle['CycleStep'][i] != 9:
                                        i+=1

                                    if Cycle['CycleStep'][i] == 9:
                                        phase9 = Cycle.loc[i, 'CycleStep']
                                        time9 = Cycle.loc[i, 'LocalDateTimeSource']
                                        phase.append(phase9)
                                        time.append(time9)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).